# http request doesn't work after change url request

Tags: ajax, http, response

I pass the url to perform http request using `$.ajax()`

```
var url = document.location.hostname == "localhost" ? "http://localhost/mydomain.pl/admin/request": "/admin/request";

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url
    ...
});
```

Everything is working fine, unless I change url for: `http://www.mydomain.pl/admin/request`. Why then it stop working? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to make an AJAX call from localhost to mydomain.pl.
By default, AJAX (or actually, XHR) [cross-domain requests are blocked by the browser as a security measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

There are ways to make that work - look into either JSONP or adding an appropriate CORS header, depending on your use case.